# MVC Jquery unobtrusive error message only showing sometimes

Tags: jquery, validation, model-view-controller, unobtrusive-validation

I have a very strange issue, I wrote a custom client side validation, now it seems as the span[data-valmsg-for="Password"] keeps comming blank, it only populated after I try to submit the form, and while I type (after trying to submit the form) but once I go to another field the message goes away.

```
$.validator.addMethod("passwordvalidation", function (value, element, param) {
console.log("false");

var msg = $('span[data-valmsg-for="Password"]').text();
console.log(msg);
return false;

},"");



$.validator.unobtrusive.adapters.add("passwordvalidation", ["firstName",   "lastName"], function (options) {
console.log("adapters");

    var params = {
        firstName: options.params.firstName,
        lastName: options.params.lastName,

    };
options.rules["passwordvalidation"] = params;

    if (options.message) {
        console.log(options.message);
        options.messages["passwordvalidation"] = options.message;
        //options.messages["passwordvalidation"] = options.message;
    }
});
```

See screenshots with debugger:
[not showing the error although validation return false](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HX3vC.png)

[After trying to submit the error shows up as long as I am in the box][2]

[Error disappear again][3]

[2] https://i.stack.imgur.com/2bhnz.png

Model:

```
[CustomPasswordValidator(FirstName = "FirstName", LastName = "LastName")]
    public string Password { get; set; }
```

Any idea why this is happening? The error message shows sometimes, I dont understand why it becomes empty.

thanks,

Idan

Comment: [3]: http://i.stack.imgur.com/DOgF6.png

Answer (score 0):

You could remove validation then re validate your form, try with this

```
 var form = $('YourForm')
                        .removeData("validator")
                        .removeData("unobtrusiveValidation");
 $.validator.unobtrusive.parse(form);
```

Comment: Where should I put this? in the .JS or cshtml? I tried both and nothing seemed to change

Comment: In .Js, are you using Data Annotations?

Comment: Yes I do, I added the model code. I dont believe this worked, I dont get it its clear that the validation is being triggered every-time I change the value, but somehow it loses the error msg..